# Unlimited 6 sided dice roller

Tags: javascript

Need help with a JavaScript assignment from School but don't know how I should do it and was hoping for some tips?

We're supposed to create a 6 sided dice roller program and the user will have the option to choose between how many dices should be rolled, min 1 and max 5 dices.

The sum of the amount of dices used should always be displayed on the page. But if a number 6 is thrown, then this should make the program disregard it to the sum and instead throw two new dices, there should be an error message displaying this when it happens.

When all the dices are thrown the total sum of all the dices should be displayed and how many times you threw the dices.

I've managed to create this so far but I'm not sure how I should do regarding the number 6 or even if I'm on the right path here?

JS

```
function rollDice() {
  var numDice = document.getElementById("diceNum").value;
  var container = document.getElementById("dieContainer");

  container.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
    var diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    container.innerHTML += '<div class="dice">' + diceRoll + '</div>';
  };

  var x, text;
  x = document.getElementById("diceNum").value;

  if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 5) {
    window.alert('Input not valid');
    document.getElementById("dieContainer").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dieContainer").style.display = "block";
  }
};
```

*EDIT*
I updated it to this now

```
let diceThrows = numDice;
let sum = 0;
while(diceThrows > 0) {
    var diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if(diceRoll == 6) {
        diceThrows += 2;
        console.log("You got a 6 och two new dices were thrown");
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "You got a 6 och two new dices were thrown";
    } else {
        sum += diceRoll;
        console.log(sum);
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Result: " + sum;
    }
    container.innerHTML += '<div class="dice">' + diceRoll + '</div>';
    diceThrows -= 1;
}
```

I managed to display the results, but wondering now if there is a way display the results without them getting reset every time you use the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace loop `for` by loop `while`:

```
let diceThrows = 6;
let sum = 0;
while(diceThrows > 0) {
    var diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if(diceRoll == 6) {
        diceThrows += 2;
    } else {
        sum += diceRoll;
    }
    container.innerHTML += '<div class="dice">' + diceRoll + '</div>';
    diceThrows -= 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It works perfectly!!! But how do I keep on adding to the result without it reseting every time you press the button?

Comment: You can store number of throws and sum in HTML containers and every new throw you can retrieve numbers from these HTML fields. Another apporach is to create variables in JS outside the function `var diceThrows = 6; var sum=0;`. I will not write full code, because you would gain more if you find it by yourself if it's your school assignment.

Comment: thank you, im thinking that i should store the results from one throw outside the function as you said.

so I should create a variable that contains the totalresults, should be var totalResults = sum

right?

Comment: Initial value of that variable should be 0, and you add every next result from `rollDice()`.

Comment: yea, but I try to store it oustide but nothing happens..

var response = (function rollDice() {
    var a;
    // calculate a
    return a;
})();

Comment: I'm not sure what's variable `response`. You should create `var totalResults=0` and in `rollDice()` add the current result `totalResults += sum`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214981/discussion-between-daca92-and-tajni).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
function rollDice() {
  var numDice = Number(document.getElementById("diceNum").value);
  if (isNaN(numDice) || numDice < 1 || numDice > 5) {
    window.alert('Input not valid');
    return
  }

  var container = document.getElementById("dieContainer");

  container.innerHTML = "";

  var total = 0

  for (var i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
    var diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    container.innerHTML += '<div class="dice">' + diceRoll + '</div>';
    if(diceRoll === 6) {
      //Increase the maximum by 1 (because ignore 6: -1; add two: +2)
      numDice++
      //Decrease the current by 1 (to ignore the 6)
      i--
      continue
    }
    total += diceRoll
  };
  document.getElementById("diceTotal").innerText = total
  document.getElementById("diceCount").innerText = numDice
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="diceNum">
<button onclick="rollDice()" >Roll Dice</button><br>
Total (without 6s): <span id="diceTotal" ></span><br>
Count of rolls (without 6s): <span id="diceCount" ></span><br>
<div id="dieContainer" ></div>
```